# In JSch, what does 'invalid handle' mean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch with Spring Integration to store files from our Spring Boot app to an SFTP server. Recently, the uploads started to fail with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to './user/2023-04-05_04:00:00_TEST_FILE_FOR_UPLOAD_TO_SFTP_PRODLIKE.csv' while uploading the file; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to write file; nested exception is 9: Invalid handle.
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:573) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:353) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    ... 166 common frames omitted
 Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to write file; nested exception is 9: Invalid handle.
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:177) ~[spring-integration-sftp-5.5.8.jar!/:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:582) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:570) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    ... 167 common frames omitted
 Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: Invalid handle.
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar!/:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:594) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar!/:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:540) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar!/:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:492) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:174) ~[spring-integration-sftp-5.5.8.jar!/:5.5.8]
    ... 169 common frames omitted
```

Shockingly, I can find nothing about this specific error when I am Googling. I see some somewhat similar results, but generally not about JSch or about a different JSch error.

Most of the somewhat similar search results seem to hint at a problem with the path, but I cannot see anything different or strange with the path to which we are trying to write.

I have turned on trace logging and it shows that we are connecting/authenticating successfully (it seems to be when it tries to write the file that it fails). I have checked for low disk space and I have tested witch changing the file name and the write directory.

**What specifically does 'handle' mean in this context and what are the rules for its validity?**

Our SFTP Impl:

```
public class SftpService {
    
    private SftpMessagingGateway gateway;

    @Autowired
    public SftpService(SftpMessagingGateway gateway) {
        this.gateway = gateway;
    }

    public boolean writeStreamToFtp(InputStream data, String filename, String path) {
        if (gateway == null) throw new IllegalStateException("SFTP Gateway is not initialized");

        Message<InputStream> mess = MessageBuilder.withPayload(data)
        .setHeader(FileHeaders.FILENAME, filename)
        .setHeader("path", path)
        .build();
        
        try {
            gateway.send(mess);
            log.info("successful persistence of report to sftp server");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("failed to persist report to sftp server", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you check the sftp server log to see if there is any more useful debugging information?

Comment: Thank you (@j_b). You comment led me to confirm the problem and then realize the answer. Thanks for pointing out my obvious blind spot - I should have requested the logs 10 seconds after seeing the issue. smh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to j_b and his comment for stating the obvious next step and putting me back on track: "check the sftp server log to see if there is any more useful debugging information".

I requested the sftp logs and found this:

```
CreateFile() failed!, Error=123, "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."
```

Not super helpful, but it did confirm it was indeed a path issue which my research suggested it might be. I took a harder look at the filename I was trying to write:

`2023-04-05_04:00:00_TEST_FILE_FOR_UPLOAD_TO_SFTP_PRODLIKE.csv`

... and I (finally) noticed the colons. Colon is not valid in filenames. Removing them resolved the issue.

**So in short, 'Invalid handle' seems to mean that Jsch failed to write to the file. Check your SFTP logs for more info. It is often a path or filename-related issue.**